# 301 redirect for multi website and store code added to url

Tags: multistore, 301-redirect

I have a specific scenario to work with and need help.

Currently I have set up for 8 years a Magento 1 multi website store with this configurations:

Magento is installed in a subfolder of a domain and its on the shop.olddomain.com

Added 4 website's and in Magento option enabled 'add store code to url's':

- website 1 - store 1 - store view 1 url: shop.olddomain.com/us/ USA
- website 2 - store 2 - store view 2 url: shop.olddomain.com/eu/ EUROPE
- website 3 - store 3 - store view 3 url: shop.olddomain.com/hr/ CROATIA
- website 4 - store 4 - store view 4 url: shop.olddomain.com/si/ SLOVENIA

Now I want for Europe, Croatia and Slovenia website to move each of them to newly bought domains separately. It needs to become:

- 2 - newdomain.eu
- 3 - newdomain.hr
- 4 - newdomain.si

and for US to stay the same:

1. olddomain.com/us/

How to achieve that with .htaccess 301 redirects (and in the same time to disable in Magento option 'add store code to url's)

Answer (score 0):

1. Installed Advanced Store Code url
   https://www.safemage.com/advanced-url-store-code.html to easy on/off storecode to url's per website one by one while developing solution
2. added subfolder in Magento root as exactly was store code I turned off for the website (like /eu) and add .htaccess redirectom rules 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
3. in main Magento .htaccess added SetEnvIF environment variable

SetEnvIf Host .*newdomain.eu.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=eu
SetEnvIf Host .*newdomain.eu.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

4. turned off Add Store Code to Url's in Magento backend for EU website
5. repeat for each other website